# Why isn't my iOS8 Application Action Extension App Icon showing up?

Tags: ios8, xcode6, ios-app-extension

My app icon is just a grey super ellipse even though I have specified a icon asset catalog in my Targets App Icons and Launch Images.

Comment: You might be able to add the `images.xcassets` file to your extension target under `Target Membership` in the file inspector in the right sidebar.

Comment: What were the steps you took to get the icon to appear? I tried setting AppIcon in a new asset catalog in my Action Extension target but nothing is showing up.

Comment: Is the Image Asset in your extensions directory? Make sure the images will be compiled with the extension to show up.

Comment: Adding the same xcassets file reference to your extensions project solves the issue. You might get some compile errors about the app icon but if you change the icons in the project settings of your extension after this, it should be fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your asset catalog in your main application isn't accessible from your application extension as they are two separate applications bundles that can only share Frameworks.

You will need to create a separate asset catalog in your action extensions folder and reference that one in your Targets.

Comment: I'm a little curious if that's really true since I read this section in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1): _For example, you might want to set up data sharing to allow a containing app and its extension to access a large set of data, such as prerendered assets._  
Curious if I'm missing something.

Comment: Data sharing a completely different concept to the assets sharing being discussed in this context. You need to think about data sharing to share data between the app and its extension at run time. What is being disused here is why and how to include files common to both the projects when building them. For ex, the app icon as in this case.

Comment: For me it works on Simulator but not on the device. It might be related to different rights of the OS to access the Assets...

Comment: I created a new asset catalog and made sure its membership was to the Extension's target. I also modified the settings to reference the new app icon image set that I created. I get this error when I compile...
` None of the input catalogs contained a matching stickers icon set or app icon set named  "AppIconExt".`

Answer (score 27):

The following worked for me creating a Share Extension, but I believe Action Extension will do the same. Note that in the case of an Action extension, you need a monochromatic version.

If you are using an asset catalog for your main application icon, you should be able to get the Extension to leverage that same asset catalog. The key for me was to:

1. Select my extension and tell it to use Asset Catalog. Select the same catalog your main icon is using. The default should be AppIcon
   [image]
2. Select the image.xcassets file in XCode Project Navigator
3. Check my extension so that it is included in the Target Membership

[image]

Comment: This results in the assets duplicated in each target.

Comment: This works fine, but remember: **Action Extensions** will use only use the alpha channel of the icon. So you most likely can't use the same icon for the main app and action extension.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: This worked for me for iphone but not for ipad simulator. Making new images (60x60 and 76x76) with only black and white solved it.

Add the image.xcassets to the extension target

[image: Add to target]

Comment: I can confirm this fixed it for myself. Note, you still have to specify the asset catalog in Targets > General > App Icons and Launch Images > App Icons Source. It 'automatically' working like in the apple docs - wasn't the case for me either.