# App Extension Icon not showing

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension

I have an app extension (Fileprovider-Extension) which Icon is not showing up when I change the FileProvider location (see screenshot). This only happens on Devices (also on the simulator) which iOS Version is 8.4!

[image]

I checked already:

- Extension have its own images.xcasset-catalog
- This images-catalog set an icon for all possible resolutions
- The build Settings of the extension Target is updated to this Asset-Catalog also the Imageset that I want to have as Extension-App-Icon
- The Asset-Catalog is already in the "Copy Bundle Resources"-Phase of the extension target

When I (initial) tap on the more button to manage my locations, I see (also on iOS 8.4 devices) the AppIcon from the Host-Application... that is really confusing me.

Another device running with iOS 8.1 shows an icon on that point but this is not the icon from the extension xcasset-catalog instead it shows the AppIcon from the Host-Application.

I also try the answers from this question: [SO: Why isnt my ios8 application action extension app icon showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097581/why-isnt-my-ios8-application-action-extension-app-icon-showing-up) but nothing helps me.

Can someone give me a hint what little point I looked over?

Answer (score 6):

1. In my case, I first added a new Asset Catalog set to my extension.
2. In that Asset Catalog, I added an new AppIcon, using the + menu at the bottom. Note the name is: **AppIcon**
3. I then added my images to the new AppIcon.
4. Then under Targets, I selected my extension, then under Build Settings under Asset Catalog Compiler - Options, I added **AppIcon** to the Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name field.

Comment: The only difference to my solution is that you named your image "AppIcon", in my project is it named with "Icon". I will try that if I come back to that project ;) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You have to add a separate Asset Catalog to your app extention, as your app and your extention are not sharing files.

Right click your app extention folder in the Xcode browser on the left -> *New File...* -> *Asset Catalog* (Resource).

Then add a App Icon to your asset catalog. Select asset catalog in the Xcode browser -> *+* -> *App Icons & Launch Images* -> *New iOS App Icon* -> Set name: *AppIcon*.

Last step: You have to set the Asset Catalog App Icon. Go to Build Settings of your extention and search for: *Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name* and enter *AppIcon*.

Done!

Comment: My app and my extension share a lot of files.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer for the same as following :

1. Select Project -> Goto "**Build Phase**"
2. Expands the "**Compile Source**"
3. Add "**images.xcassests**" of your mainProject

> The bigest advantage of following above step is "*Memory Management*" + "*Decrease Size Of Project Too*".

Hope It helps...