# Xcode 8.1 Action Extension Icon

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, ios-app-extension

How do you set an Action Extension icon in Xcode 8.1? There is no "App Icons and Launch Images" section for the Action Extension in the general tab or Asset Catalog App Icon Name Set in the build settings.

Comment: it use the same xcasset as the main app icon, it have watch app and notification icon there

Comment: This will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097581/why-isnt-my-ios8-application-action-extension-app-icon-showing-up/27333408#27333408